# Accessing a nested list of objects in dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart, nested-lists

I have a list of Care requirements name care requirements list which consist of requirement_id, requirement_name and care_levels_list which is inside the care requirements list.The care requirements list is retrieved through an API response and is in the format

**[CareRequirement(1, Requirement 1, [{care_level_id: 1, care_level_name: no-help, price: 2000.00}, {care_level_id: 2, care_level_name: supervise, price: 1000.00}, {care_level_id: 3, care_level_name: assist, price: 1000.00}]), CareRequirement(2, Requirement 2, [{care_level_id: 2, care_level_name: supervise, price: 3000.00}]),**

how can I access the price of the care level id 1 of requirement 1?

**CareRquirement model**

```
class CareRequirement extends Equatable {
 int id = 0;
 String name = '';
 List careLevelsList = [];


CareRequirement(
  {required this.id, required this.name, required this.careLevelsList});

 @override
 List<Object?> get props => [id, name, careLevelsList];

  @override
  CareRequirement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    careLevelsList = json['care_levels'];
  }

  Map toJson() {
   Map jsonData = {
     "id": id,
      "name": name,
      "care_levels": careLevelsList,
    };
    return jsonData;
    }

    static pure() {
     return CareRequirement(
        id: 0,
        name: '',
        careLevelsList: [],
     );
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you share the model for `CareRequirement`

Comment: would it not just be `careRequirements[0].careLevelsList[0].price`?

Comment: @meditat I posted the care requirements model :)